# Gives an error in the test for creating a blog topic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

I'm testing my code, and I'm faced with the problem of creating a blog theme.

Error:

```
client = <starlette.testclient.TestClient object at 0x7fe57e1c1bd0>
normal_user_token_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgxNzYyODk3fQ.Uhlu3wZmwUSac0ezNcTHwvZntaLWbnvaqVYUIlPwKic'}

    def test_create_topic(client, normal_user_token_headers):
        data = TopicCreate(
            title="451",
            description="here not marketing",
            tags="python",
            image="jpeg.jpg",
        )
        response = client.post("/topics/create-topic/", json=data.dict(), headers=normal_user_token_headers)
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 422 == 200
E        +  where 422 = <Response [422 Unprocessable Entity]>.status_code

tests/test_routes/test_topics.py:29: AssertionError
```

test_topics.py:

```
import pytest
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime, date


class TopicBase(BaseModel):
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None
    tags: str | None = None
    image: str | None = None
    date_posted: date | None = datetime.now().date().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")


class TopicCreate(TopicBase):
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None
    tags: str | None = None
    image: str | None = None


def test_create_topic(client, normal_user_token_headers):
    data = TopicCreate(
        title="451",
        description="here not marketing",
        tags="python",
        image="jpeg.jpg",
    )
    response = client.post("/topics/create-topic/", json=data.dict(), headers=normal_user_token_headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

route_topics.py:

```
router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/create-topic/", response_model=ShowTopic)
def create_topic(
    title: str = Form(...),
    description: str = Form(...),
    image: UploadFile = File(default=None),
    tags: str = Form(...),
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user_from_token),
):
    topics = TopicCreate(title=title, description=description, tags=tags)
    if image:
        topics.image = handle_file_upload(image)
    elif not image:
        topics.image = ""
    return create_new_topic(topic=topics, db=db, owner_id=current_user.id)
```

schemas.py:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


# shared properties
class TopicBase(BaseModel):
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None
    tags: str | None = None
    image: str | None = None
    date_posted: date | None = datetime.now().date()


# this will be used to validate data while creating a Topic
class TopicCreate(TopicBase):
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None
    tags: str | None = None
    image: str | None = None


# this will be used to format the response to not to have id,owner_id etc
class ShowTopic(TopicBase):
    title: str
    description: str
    tags: str
    image: str 
    date_posted: date

    class Config:  # to convert non dict obj to json
        orm_mode = True
```

conftest.py:

```
import os
import sys
from typing import Any
from typing import Generator

import pytest
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
# this is to include backend dir in sys.path so that we can import from db,main.py

from db.base import Base
from schemas.topics import TopicCreate
from db.session import get_db
from apis.base import api_router
from core.config import settings
from tests.utils.users import authentication_token_from_email


def start_application():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(api_router)
    return app


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test_db.db"
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
# Use connect_args parameter only with sqlite
SessionTesting = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def app() -> Generator[FastAPI, Any, None]:
    """
    Create a fresh database on each test case.
    """
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # Create the tables.
    _app = start_application()
    yield _app
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def db_session(app: FastAPI) -> Generator[SessionTesting, Any, None]:
    connection = engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = SessionTesting(bind=connection)
    yield session  # use the session in tests.
    session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client(
    app: FastAPI, db_session: SessionTesting
) -> Generator[TestClient, Any, None]:
    """
    Create a new FastAPI TestClient that uses the `db_session` fixture to override
    the `get_db` dependency that is injected into routes.
    """

    def _get_test_db():
        try:
            yield db_session
        finally:
            pass

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = _get_test_db
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client

    
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def normal_user_token_headers(client: TestClient, db_session: Session):
    return authentication_token_from_email(
        client=client, email=settings.TEST_USER_EMAIL, db=db_session
        )
```

I tried using data instead of json in the post method in the test, to no avail. And in general, while I have no particular idea where the source of the problem is.

Comment: I don't fully understand the framework you are using but you might try passing `files=` even though you have a default set to `None`.  Maybe the server is expecting a different content type anyways.  The test client doc has an example https://www.starlette.io/testclient/

Comment: You're using `TopicCreate` as your model and submitting JSON, but your endpoint expects form variables and a file upload - not a JSON model. Use `data` with the testclient request to send Form variables instead. If you look at the body of the response you'll also see an error message explaining what is missing from the expected format.

Comment: @MatsLindh  used **data** instead of json, but it still gives the same error

Comment: @IanWilson, I doubt that he expects a different data type, because to validate the data in Topic Create, I specified rows everywhere in the data types. Yes, and I have already tried to insert other types of data, and everything was also problematic.

Comment: @Rauf44 Yeah, if you're going to upload file as post data as well you'll have to do that in a proper way instead of just sending the file name. Ian linked the relevant documentation above. You'll also want to look at the body of the response returned when failing, as that will contain the actual reason why your request failed.